# what's sort rule in relate to StringComparison

Tags: c#, .net

I'm new to C#, just a question on StringComparison. We know that StringComparison has  Ordinal, OrdinalIgnoreCare etc. And some docs say :

***Ordinal :Compares strings using ordinal (binary) sort rules***

but I don't understand how sort can relate to string comparsion, don't we just compute ASCII for each character to see if they match? for example, if we code:

```
string s1 = "Hello";
string s2 = "HELLO";

if (s1.Equals(s2, StringComparison.Ordinal)) {
   ...
}
```

and if we want to compare s1 with s2, the first char "H" is the same. the next char of s1 is e with ASCII of 101 and 'E' is 69, 101 doesn't equal 69, so s1 is not the same as s2, so there is no sorting thing involved here?

Comment: Well, 69 < 101, so "HELLO" would sort *before* "Hello".

Answer (score 0):

You're right. But, ordering (or sorting) is a predominant application of comparing. So, they mixed the ideas together somewhat. Except for `Equals`, comparing two strings would give their sort order.

Note: .NET uses the UTF-16 character encoding of the Unicode character set for text datatypes. So, it's the sequences of UTF-16 code units that are being compared for "binary".